# Count and Signum function

Tags: terraform

Can someone explain to me as to why signum would be used here.

terraform-azure-module-resourcegroup

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  count    = signum(var.create ? 1 : 0)
  location = var.location
  tags     = var.tags
}




module "rg-sharegate" {
  source             = "git::ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/*"
  name_suffix        = "test"
  location           = var.location
  create             = true
}
```

Can't I simply use:

```
count    = var.create ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: I guess it depends on what `var.create` is, but if it is of type `bool` then yes, you do not need the `signum` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyze each part of this expression to see what it does.

First, the truth table of `var.create ? 1 : 0` across all valid values of `var.create`:

| `var.create` | result |
| --- | --- |
| `true` | `1` |
| `false` | `0` |

So the full [range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_function) of this expression is {`1`,`0`}.

We then pass that to [signum](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/signum), which has the following truth table:

| `signum` argument | result |
| --- | --- |
| `0` | `0` |
| > `0` | `1` |
| < `0` | `-1` |

Finally, we can combine those two truth tables together to get the truth table for the entire expression:

| `var.create` | `signum` argument | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `true` | `1` (> `0`) | `1` |
| `false` | `0` | `0` |

So we can see that with only `1` and `0` as possible inputs `signum` behaves as an [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function), just returning its input unchanged.

Therefore the `signum` call is redundant and removing it will not change the result. The `signum` call here does not seem to be needed.

Comment: thanks Martin, appreciate the explanation